# Por qué los valores de request.getParameter llegan nulos a mi servlet desde mi ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

tengo un ajax que se encarga de enviar los datos de mi formulario jsp al servlet para ser procesados y guardados donde corresponda, pero el problema es que los request.getParameters llegan nulos. Ya había hecho un método que hiciera lo mismo y funcionaba bien, claro que no tenía tantos datos en el formulario y el javascript estaba adentro del jsp. En el formulario real el jsp y el archivo js están por separados.
Aquí dejo mis códigos. Por favor, necesito ayuda.
JSP:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="form_valorar">
                <input type="text" style="visibility: hidden" name="idProducto"/>
                <div class="info">     

                </div>

                <div class="campos_valoracion">
                    <div class="estrellas">
                        <span class="titulo">Valora tu experiencia</span>
                        <div class="estrella">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valoracion" value="mala" id="mala" />
                            <label for="mala">
                                <span class="estrella_mala">
                                    <img src="img/estrella_vacia.png" src="estrella mala">
                                    <span>Mala</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estrella">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valoracion" value="buena" id="buena" />
                            <label for="buena">
                                <span class="estrella_buena">
                                    <img src="img/estrella_vacia.png" src="estrella buena">
                                    <span>Buena</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estrella">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valoracion" value="excelente" id="excelente" />
                            <label for="excelente">
                                <span class="estrella_excelente">
                                    <img src="img/estrella_vacia.png" src="estrella excelente">
                                    <span>Excelente</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="file" name="img_boleta" 
                               id="img_boleta" placeholder="Imagen principal" 
                               class="img-upload"/>
                        <label for="img_boleta">
                            <span>
                                <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Foto de la Boleta
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" name="num_boleta" id="num_boleta"
                               placeholder="Número de la boleta"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boton">
                        <input type="submit" name="valorar" value="Valorar oferta"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

JS

```
 $("#form_valorar").submit(function (e) {
    var mensaje_error = "";
    if (!$("#mala").is(":checked") &&
            !$("#buena").is(":checked") &&
            !$("#excelente").is(":checked")) {
        mensaje_error += "<li>Debes dar un puntuación a la valoración</li>";
    }
    if ($("#img_boleta").val().length == 0) {
        mensaje_error += "<li>Debes dar subir la imagen de la boleta</li>";
    }
    if ($("#num_boleta").val().length == 0) {
        mensaje_error += "<li>Debes indicar el numero de la boleta adjunta</li>";
    }
    if (mensaje_error.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div.errores ul").html(mensaje_error);
        if ($("div.errores").css('display') == 'none') {
            $("div.errores").slideToggle("fast");
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("div.errores").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        valora();
    }
});
function valora() {
    var form = $('#form_valorar')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "valorar_oferta",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        error: function () {

            alert("Error");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result === 'true') {
                window.location = 'mensaje_valorar.jsp';
            }
            if (result === 'false') {
                $(".dialog_guardar .titulo").html("Hubo un error al procesar la solicitud");
                $(".dialog_guardar img").attr("src", "img/error.png");
                $(".dialog_guardar p.mensaje").html("Ha ocurrido un error al procesar\n\
            la solicitud, intentalo nuevamente más tarde o ponte en contacto\n\
            con el personal de MisOfertas.");
                $('.dialog_guardar').css('top', screenTop + ($(window).height()) * 0.20);
                $(".dialog_guardar").slideToggle('fast');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Servlet

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(false);
    int id_consumidor = Integer.parseInt(sesion.getAttribute("id_consumidor").toString());
    String pirnttt = request.getParameter("idProducto");
    int id_producto = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idProducto"));
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    boolean valorada = true;
    for (Valoracion og : valoracionFacade.findAll()) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(og.getIdProducto().getIdProducto().toString()) == id_producto
                && Integer.parseInt(og.getIdConsumidor().getIdConsumidor().toString()) == id_consumidor) {
            valorada = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (valorada) {
        int puntuacion = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valoracion"));
        int boleta = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num_boleta"));
        Part filePart = request.getPart("img_boleta"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
        String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.
        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileContent.available()];
        fileContent.read(buffer);
        File targetFile = new File("C:\\Users\\TomasIgnacioTorresCa\\Desktop\\MisOfertas.com\\web\\img\\boletas\\" + fileName);
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        outStream.write(buffer);
        String ruta = "/img/boletas/" + fileName;
        out.print(valoracionFacade.Valorar(id_consumidor, ruta, puntuacion, boleta, id_producto));
    } else {
        out.print(valorada);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré mi error, me faltaba agregar el elemento @MultipartConfig

```
import com.MisOfertas.Beans.ValoracionFacade;
import com.MisOfertas.Entity.Valoracion;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 *
 * @author Coleg
 */
@WebServlet(name = "valorar_oferta", urlPatterns = {"/valorar_oferta"})
@MultipartConfig
```